# How parse json object and json array together

Tags: android, json, web-services

i have two situation of Json output .
one is data that found and i have  a json array and a json object like this:

```
{"data":"yes"}[{"id":"10","number":"7","text":"text7","desc":"text7_again","user_code":"0"},{"id":"11","number":"8","text":"text8","desc":"text8_again","user_code":"1"}]
```

other situation is that data not found :

```
{"data":"no"}
```

just one json object.

how parse this data in android client for support two situtaion?

Comment: The "yes" version is not valid json, so there won't be any problem parsing it...

Comment: how i can implement that mode? use two array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should validate your json in http://jsonlint.com/ if you test it you will look that is a wrong json. So, for make it right, in your server your response should look something like this:

```
{"data":"yes","response":[{"id":"10","number":"7","text":"text7","desc":"text7_again","user_code":"0"},{"id":"11","number":"8","text":"text8","desc":"text8_again","user_code":"1"}]}
```

And in that case, in android

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response); 
if (jsonObj.getString("data").compareTo("yes") == 0) {
   JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("response");
   //To-Do another code
}
```

and that's all

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible case: (you need to fix your json format)

Success -

```
 string resultJSON = 
   {"success":true,
      "data":[
          {"id":"10","number":"7","text":"text7","desc":"text7_again","user_code":"0"},
          {"id":"11","number":"8","text":"text8","desc":"text8_again","user_code":"1"}]}
```

Failed -

```
string resultJSON =
    {"success":false}
```

Then

```
JSONObject jsonRoot  = new JSONObject(resultJSON);
 bool isSuccess = jsonRoot.getBoolean("success");
 if (isSuccess) {
  // do the array parser
  for(int i=0; i<jsonData.lenght;i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonData.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = jsonObj.getString("id");   // get the value of id
        String desc = jsonObj.getString("desc");  // and so on...
  }
 }
```